# Требуется помощь в коррекции кода

Tags: php

народ.
У меня есть вот такой пример (код с другой функции)

```
<option value="0"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 0): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Демонстрация</option>
<option value="1"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 1): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Клиент</option>
<option value="2"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 2): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Техническая поддержка</option>
<option value="3"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 3): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Администрация</option>
<option value="4"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 4): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Старшая администрация</option>
<option value="5"<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 5): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Руководство</option>
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы не в списке было, а просто был вывод текста.
Допустим если у меня user_access_level 5 он выдавал просто текст "**Руководство**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php if($user['user_access_level'] == 5): ?>Руководство<?php endif; ?>` и так с каждым. Если нужен перенос строк - `<BR>`

Comment: Если нужно проверять много значений, тогда лучше сделать через switch